# How to reflect that two objects of subclasses never expired?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

superclass:

```
public class Card 

{


 ...

       public boolean isExpired() //Card never expires.

       { 

             return false; 

       }

}
```

subclasses:

```
public class IDCard extends Card {}

public class PhoneCard extends Card {}
```

Question:
The ID card and the phone card don’t expire. What should you do to reflect this fact in your implementation?

Comment: So do you want us to do your homework for you?

Answer (score 1):

Hints only!  I'm not coding this for you, because it looks like a "learning exercise".

You could implement the behaviour of the superclass so that an instance of `Card` *can be* expired.  And override the behaviour it in the *relevant* subclasses where necessary.  You then need to decide whether the "unexpirable" subclasses are going to use or ignore the variable in the superclass that says whether the card is expired ... and implement accordingly.

Alternatively, you could implement the superclass as an `abstract` class and make `isExpired` an `abstract` method.

I'm not going to say which is "the right way" to do this.  I want **you** to think that through for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

DON'T override the isExpired method in your subclasses IDCard and PhoneCard as your parent class Card already gives you the 'don't expire' behavior. Make sure if there is a field in your parent class called isExpired then it should be private and there should be no setter for it.